# Filtering Data Table as Repeater DataSource (asp. net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have nested repaters for group the data. All data in same table and they all have QUESTION_GROUP column. I'm passing group name from parent repeater for child repeater in Parent's Item Data Bound. But i cant set it as child repeater data source. How can i filter multiple data from Data Table for repeater DataSource?

```
protected void ParentRepeaterDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater rp = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater");            
        rp.DataSource = FixedQuestions.Select("QUESTION_GROUP='" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Q_Group").ToString() + "'");
        rp.DataBind();
    }
```

Q_Group is coming from parent repeater. QUESTION_GROUP is a column in fixedquestions(DataTable).

> I'm asking, How can i get a part of Data Table which filtered by column(For Repeater Data Source)?

Comment: What do you mean you can't set data source? Please explain what is happening, an exception? Empty repeater? What is FixedQuestion? There is not enough information to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Esko Sorry. FixedQuestion is the Data Table that all data in it. I want to get some data from it like "DataTable.Select(Where question_group=Parent Repeater's Data Item)". I have an error now (Object reference not set an instance of an object). Looks like my source is not right type for being Data Source of repeater.

Comment: Edit all this additional information to your question. What line throws the exception? Is rp null? is FixedQuestions null? there still is not enough information to help you out, we have no way of knowing what is wrong with that piece of code.

Comment: @Esko Actually i think this post has enough inf. for what i'm asking. I am asking; "How can i get a part of table, as a Repeater Data Source which filtered by column?" Or:"How can i get a part of table, as a new Data Table which filtered by column?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to filter the table before binding it to the nested Repeater.

```
rp.DataSource = FixedQuestions.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("columnName") == "myValue").CopyToDataTable();
```

The above snippet will work as long as there are remaining rows after filtering. Otherwise you will get a "The source contains no DataRows" error.
The below snippet will check if there are any rows before calling `CopyToDataTable()`.

```
        DataTable dtFiltered = new DataTable();
        var dtFilteredTemp = FixedQuestions.AsEnumerable().Where(X => X.Field<string>("columnName") == "myValue");
        if (dtFilteredTemp.AsDataView().Count > 0)
        {
            dtFiltered = dtFilteredTemp.CopyToDataTable();
        }
        rp.DataSource = dtFiltered;
```

Comment: I've tryed your first snipped and i got "Source contains no DataRows" error. So i tryed second one, there was no error but it doesnt work correctly. S Ro debug the code and saw dtFiltered has 0 row. I cant understand. :/

Comment: Then what you filtered for returned 0 results. Try filtering on a value that quarantees to return rows.

Comment: I had already checked that :( I think my FixedQuestion table might coming empty. I'm getting it with session(And im using your code like -> (DataTable)Session["FixedQuest"]).AsEnumerable().Where......) I think i should check my session or update panel or something else. Because your code looks correct and sensible. Thanks for now :)

Comment: That could be it. You can store the session as an unfiltered datatable first and check if there are any rows. If that is the case you can check the `Where` statement (note that the strings are case sensitive in the filtering)

Comment: I've checked my Session table. It has rows like correctly(However, i cant see data in it, but i can see columns and rows correct. It has data). My column name is "QUESTION_GROUP"  and i'm using big letters. I must big right?

Comment: Should look like this, assuming the column QUESTION_GROUP contains string. `.Where(x => x.Field<string>("QUESTION_GROUP").ToLower() == DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Q_Group").ToString().ToLower());`

Comment: I noticed somethig. I said it might be about my Session data table. I think it is. I tryed debug again and looked in that table. Rows(there were 2 like it must be)->ResultVİew->[0]SystemData.Row->ItemArray->And i should see here columns and datas like [0] | "Data here" But i see only the columns with no data. It confused me there are rows and columns but no data. So, your code correct and it will be usefull for me when i handle this problem. I should do it first. I'll be feedback for you.

Comment: It was my mistake somewhere in back. I was looking wrong plase for to fix it. I'm binding my repeaters now. Your code works great. Thank u for your help and time :)

Comment: No problem. Happy programming.